# Migrating to Google Cloud Endpoints v2

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-eclipse-plugin, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I am currently using Cloud Endpoints v1 in an existing application, but I would like to update it to v2 for App Engine in Java.  I have reviewed the [migration guide](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/migrating), but this only provides steps for migrating a Maven project.  I am not using Maven, but I am using the Java App Engine SDK and Google Eclipse plugin to develop, test, and deploy my endpoints.  I am having trouble getting v2 of the Cloud Endpoints Framework to run due to conflicts with the existing dependencies in the [App Engine SDK](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/download).  How can I override the v1 dependencies in the App Engine SDK so that I can migrate to v2?  Is this possible, or should I convert my project to a Maven project?

Answer (score 1):

I believe GPE is deprecated. However, you should be able to right click on your App Engine project, select `Build Path > Configure Build Path`, and add the `endpoints-framework` JAR under the Libraries tab. Make sure to go to Order and Export and move the endpoints-framework above the App Engine SDK, or you're likely to encounter issues.

Comment: I followed your instruction, but I am receiving an error trying to start the local dev server to test the endpoints.  I am also using Guice injection with the endpoints framework.  `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.server.spi.ServletInitializationParameters.getServiceClasses()Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet;`

Comment: I am using the same configuration of the endpoints framework in an existing Maven project and works with out any problems.  I still believe there is some type of conflict between the Java App Engine SDK which includes the old appengine-endpoints jar.

Comment: I have cleaned the project in Eclipse and also set the ordering of the libraries and jars such that the new endpoints-framework.jar is listed first.  There is still an issue when building the project that seems to be a result of the presence of the old appengine-endpoints.jar.  The old configuration gets created in the web.xml during build. @saiyr Is it possible to exclude the appengine-endpoints.jar from the App Engine SDK Library?

Answer (score 0):

In order to override the include appengine-endpoints.jar from the App Engine SDK for Java, I added a class-loader-config to the appengine-web.xml.

`<classloader-config>
      <priority-specifier filename="endpoints-framework-2.0.3.jar/>
 </class-loader-config>`

I've also disabled the Google Cloud Endpoint Builder in Eclipse.  Properties>Builders and unchecked Google App Engine Cloud Endpoints Builder.

Comment: Did you end up using maven, or did you manage to avoid that? It is time for me to finally migrate to GCE v2, and I will do everything to not have to use maven.